# "identifier is undefined" error in template class member function

Tags: c++, templates, member-functions

I want to create a 'complex' template class to perform complex number calculations. But when I create a member function, compiler throws a "identifier is undefined" error when I try to call that function.

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class complex {
private:
    T rl, im;
public:
    complex() : rl(0), im(0) {}
    complex(T x, T y) : rl(x), im(y) {}
    void read();
    complex<T> conjugate (const complex<T>& param);     
};
template <class T>
void complex<T>::read() {
    std::cout << "Enter the real no. and the imaginery part: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> rl >> im;
}
template< class T >
complex<T> complex<T>::conjugate(const complex<T>& param) {
    complex temp;
    temp.rl = param.rl;
    temp.im = -param.im;
    return temp;
}
```

And the main function looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include "complex.h"
int main() {
complex<int> ob1(4, 5);
complex<int> result;
result = conjugate(ob1); //not able to call conjugate, "identifier is undefined" error
result.display();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `complex temp` in conjugate function should be `complex<T> temp`

Comment: Why does `conjugate` take a parameter *at all*?

Comment: Either call ob1.conjungate or have conjugate be static and take a parameter.

Comment: And `result` isn't even defined. Pretty sure you should be doing [something like this](http://ideone.com/kJ1aoI).

Comment: Thanks for helping. Got it to work using all your suggestions. I appreciate it. @WhozCraig Edited to include the result definition. Thanks for your code.